# How to remove white place in UWP App (XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to remove this white borders (marked orange pen). I want that my App fit 880px and be full width. In My XAML Document I did next

```
<Page
    x:Class="FirstScreen.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:FirstScreen"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="880" Height="600">

    <Grid Width="880" Height="600" Background="Black">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image]

But I still have white borders! what I need that my App will compile with out this borders?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop window resize, by using [TryResizeView(Size)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-viewmanagement-applicationview-tryresizeview(windows-foundation-size)) function, but its not recommended to do resize by code behind, when user is engaged in UI.

I will share the solution here , but again  ITS NOT RECOMENDED.

in App.xaml.cs , OnLaunched event , once all your UI related code completed, at the end , place this line of code

```
 ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBoundsChanged += App_VisibleBoundsChanged;
```

and create event for "App_VisibleBoundsChanged"

```
 private void App_VisibleBoundsChanged(ApplicationView sender, object args)
    { 
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);
    }
```

declare a global variable for Size

```
Size size = new Size(800, 600);
```

This will make your app, always work in specified size. But the user feels like a glitch in app, when they try to resize .

Here is the entire App.xaml.cs code

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    Size size = new Size(800, 600);

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
    /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
        {
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            }
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBoundsChanged += App_VisibleBoundsChanged;
    }

    private void App_VisibleBoundsChanged(ApplicationView sender, object args)
    {
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the `Grid` a width as 880, so the Grid is not fill in all the window. Just remove the width and height that you've added.

Comment: thats not helps, result same

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко remove the width of the page you defined as well

Comment: but how to setup window width?

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко why you need to set the window width? What are you trying to implement?

Comment: I want implement App with custom width, that provided me designer, the design of this app is not suggests full width. so next problem I cant block resize window. Do you know how to block resize?

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко If I understand you correctly, you want to keep your app show at a specific size, is that right? If it is, then I have to say that it is not possible to do that. You could pre-set a window size for your app. But you can't disable the resize when a user resizes the window.